Question about Gaussian Mixture Model

A random vector $X = (X_1, …, X_k)'$ is said to have the multivariate normal distribution if it satisfies the following equivalent conditions.

Every linear combination of its components $Y = a_1X_1 + … + a_kX_k$ is normally distributed
i.e. $a^TX=\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i$ is Gaussian $\forall a\in\mathbb R^n$.


I understood this line I want to understand is this statement will be true for the Gaussian mixture model also where we will have say $m$ component of the multivariate? Or can I say that it will give us the mixture of univariates?

A multivariate Gaussian distribution is not the same thing as a Gaussian mixture.  For example a multivariate Gaussian will have a single peak in the likelihood while a Gaussian mixture may have many.  Which are you interested in?

@Henry I think the OP tried to ask whether "a finite mixture of MVN is characterized by all linear combinations of components being a finite mixture of univariate normals".

@ZackFisher Yes that is what I am asking!

Intuitively, I believe this is true. Below is some informal justification.
By Cramér-Wold theorem, we can characterize a multivariate distribution through its univariate projections. This result is not specific to MVN.
It remains to check that any univariate projections of a finite mixture MVN is a finite mixture of univariate normals.
If
$$\newcommand{\T}{\mathsf{T}}
 Y\sim \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \text{MVN}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i), $$
then we can write it as a hierarchical model
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rl}
Z&\sim \text{Multinomial}(1,p) \\
Y\mid Z & \stackrel{d}= \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i X_i
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $p=[p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k]^\T$.
For any linear combination $\ell^\T Y$, we have
$$
\ell^\T Y \mid Z \stackrel{d}= \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i \ell^\T X_i \stackrel{d}= \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i U_i
$$
where $U_i\sim \text{N}\left(\ell^\T \mu_i, \ell^\T \Sigma_i \ell \right)$. So marginally, $\ell^\T Y$ is a mixture of univariate normals.
